# Accessing BOM information from a Maven projet using that BOM

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-bom

I have a BOM project which contains some information for some dependencies, with a `pom.xml` like this for example :

```xml
[...]

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

[...]
```

Naturally, I'm referencing that BOM in some Maven project that uses the same dependency but without the version, since it will be resolved from the BOM.

However, I would need to access and retrieve the version of the dependencies contained in the BOM from the Maven project (the one using the BOM). Let's say I need the version of `commons-lang3` to be in the description of the `pom.xml` of my project, like :

```xml
<description>(insert here variable or something to retrieve the version from BOM)</description>
```

To achieve this, I could use a plugin in the BOM to write the contents of the `pom.xml` to a file like `versions.properties` and then read that file with the same plugin from the project. However, that kind of defeats the whole purpose of the BOM.

I checked the Maven Dependency Plugin and there might be something in it to help me, but I haven't had any luck finding anything yet.

Comment: To use a BOM you have to use scope:import and type:pom (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms)

Comment: I don't think you can put it in the description. What is the real use case you have in mind?